# Toggle flip cards in React

Tags: css, reactjs, state, styled-components

I'm trying to create a flip card effect where if I click on a card it flips over. However, if I then click on another card, I'd like the original card to flip back. This means having some sort of global toggle on all of the cards but one that gets overridden by the local toggle. I'm not sure of the most React-y way to do this - I've tried implementing it with the useState hook at both levels, but I'm not having much luck.

I'm using styled-components, with the 'flipped' prop determining the Y-transform.

Here's the flip card component, and you can see what I've tried so far:

```
const PortfolioItem = props => {
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false)

  return (
    <PortfolioItemStyles onClick={() => setFlipped(!flipped)}>

// what I'm trying to say here is, if the individual card's 'flipped' is set to true, 
use that, otherwise use props.flipped which will be set to false

      <PortfolioItemInnerStyle flipped={flipped ? flipped : props.flipped}>
        <PortfolioItemFront >
          {props.image}
          <PortfolioImageCover className="img-cover" />
          <PortfolioItemHeader>{props.title}</PortfolioItemHeader>
        </PortfolioItemFront>
        <PortfolioItemBack>
            <h1>Hello there</h1>
        </PortfolioItemBack>
      </PortfolioItemInnerStyle>
    </PortfolioItemStyles>
  )
}

function PortfolioStyles() {
    const [ allFlipped, setAllFlipped ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <PortfolioContainer>
      {portfolioItems.map(item => {
        return <PortfolioItem image={item.image} flipped={allFlipped} title={item.title} onClick={() => setAllFlipped(false)} />
      })}
    </PortfolioContainer>
  )
}
```

The logic I'm using is clearly faulty, but I was wondering what would be the 'best practice' way of doing this? In vanilla JS you'd use a single event handler and use event.target on it to make sure you were isolating the element, but I'm not sure how to handle this in React. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally manage the state only on the container component. Let's say you will store an index of the flipped card instead of a true/false status. The onClick would then change the current index and the flipped is computed by checking `index === currentIndex`. Something like this:

```
const PortfolioItem = props => {

  return (
    <PortfolioItemStyles>
      <PortfolioItemInnerStyle flipped={props.flipped}>
        <PortfolioItemFront >
          {props.image}
          <PortfolioImageCover className="img-cover" />
          <PortfolioItemHeader>{props.title}</PortfolioItemHeader>
        </PortfolioItemFront>
        <PortfolioItemBack>
            <h1>Hello there</h1>
        </PortfolioItemBack>
      </PortfolioItemInnerStyle>
    </PortfolioItemStyles>
  )
}

function PortfolioStyles() {
    const [ currentFlippedIndex, setCurrentFlippedIndex ] = useState(-1);

  return (
    <PortfolioContainer>
      {portfolioItems.map((item, index) => {
        return <PortfolioItem image={item.image} flipped={index === currentFlippedIndex} title={item.title} onClick={() => setCurrentFlippedIndex(index)} />
      })}
    </PortfolioContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it's not working... the logic looks good to me

Comment: Done it, I had to move the handle to the individual card as a prop. Thanks for your help!